# Conflict between how PEP8 E127 is supposed to work and warnings I get

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

Here below is a screenshot of my code saying it doesn't respect E127 from the PEP 8 rules:
[image]
However, in this [link](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E127.html), what is explained as good practice is what I have. Furtheremore, when I use the shortcuts `Ctrl + Alt + I` (and `Alt + Shift + Enter`) which are the PyCharm shortcuts to format the line (and the file) according to PEP 8, this (above) is the formatting I obtain (and if I deviate from it, pressing those bring me back to this (above) formatting).

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Another situation when it's not inside parentheses but with an `=` sign where niko's solution does not apply: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIAma.png.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using tabs instead of spaces? Because I pycharm will complain about E128 even though it lines up perfectly when using tabs. (which I suppose it technically a bug in pycharm)

Comment: After deactivating "Using tab characters" in PyCharm I seem to have fewer problems. So I'm pretty sure you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Idk about your specific question, but personally, the way I indent is as follows

```
def foo(
    x: int,
    y: int = 1
) -> int:
    res = bar(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        some_very_long_arg="some_very_long_arg"
    )
    return res
```

PyCharm never complained about that style (I don't think it is against any PEP but I might be wrong).

It feels easier to read when there are many and/or long parameters inside of functions (calls).

A somewhat in the middle approach would be something like this

```
def foo(
    x: int, y: int = 1
) -> int:
    res = bar(
        x=x, y=y,
        some_very_long_arg="some_very_long_arg"
    )
    return res
```

---

**Edit**

Long strings

```
string = "very long " \
         "string"
# or
other_string = "string"
string = "very long " + \
         other_string + "!"
```

Comment: It actually doesn't go against PEP 8 (at least according to PyCharm). Is it the "only" way to respect PEP 8 then ? I'm not quite used to this sort of formatting but if this is the norm, I might as well go for it. I'll see if anyone else has a way of respecting PEP 8 with my way of formatting, but I've seen yours plenty of time so I might switch if no one has a way of respecting PEP 8 without `\n` after parentheses.

Comment: How do you do in this situation though: https://i.imgur.com/rKEtFwT.png ?

Comment: I defo wouldn't say it is the *norm*. In fact, I used to indent the way you do. Then I copied the above style from a coworker (at first I was not a fan but in hindsight it feels much more efficient). Also, there are a quite few libraries where this style has been applied.

Comment: See the edit for long strings (It's basically just PyCharm's default). PS: Beware of passing data into your SQL queries - it is usually a good idea to pass them as function parameters in `psycopg2` or `sqlalchemy`

Comment: Hi, i've seen your edit but this doesn't work because I'm concatenating a string with a variable which is also a string. Cf. https://i.imgur.com/npMvNgb.png. EDIT: not sure I understand what you mean, is it compatible with `pyodbc`?

Comment: The indent must be looked up on the last token before split, and then indent left from there..

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Fair enough, added another example, but the rationale is pretty much the same.

Comment: @niko well this is what I have in the first screenshot and I have a warning (https://i.imgur.com/rKEtFwT.png). Sorry if I'm missing something obvious;

Comment: @Kris I'm not sure I understand what you mean by token.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows Maybe try writing it in one line, then hit `enter` with the cursor right after the `+` (PyCharm should auto-indent) and see if you still have the message. Cannot think of much else :/

Comment: That's what I did and it still doesn't solve the problem (it comes back to the same) :/ Even using `Ctrl + Alt + I` doesn't change anything.

Comment: (just realized what you mean by function parameters, I understand it is another solution that works, but why is it better? might be a bit off topic though)

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows There are a few reasons: The main reason is it avoids SQL-Injections (feel free to read up on it). Second, it allows more abstraction. Third, it is arguably cleaner.